# Can I somehow use CS4 to build an AS2 project that uses the new FLVPlayback component?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flvplayback, actionscript-2, cs4

We have a huge project written in AS2 with the old FLVPlayback component which was responsible for progressive download playback of FLVs.  I'd like to support MP4 files (which is now supported in Flash 9 and up with the updated FLVPlayback) but would like to not have to rewrite all of the project.

I've seen in various posts on SO surmised that one could possibly use CS4 to open the AS2 project, replace the FLVPlayback component with newer one and build.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, MP4 decoding is not available in AS2, no matter the player.